# How to make own custom modal events

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am making my very own modal. But I need to have the events for my modal just like the events of modal in bootstrap. Because I want something to happen once my own modal has been shown to the users

My question is what is the equivalent of these bootstrap modal event into plain vanilla js

> show.bs.modal
> shown.bs.modal
> hide.bs.modal
> hidden.bs.modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for that. Hope the below example helps.

When the `show_modal` function calls it will trigger the `modal_show` event.

When the `hide_modal` function calls it will trigger the `modal_hide` event.

We can listen both events in anywhere like `window.addEventListener('modal_show'...`

```js
function show_modal() {
    // show modal logic here
    
    // Create a custom event
    const event = new Event('modal_show');
    // Dispatch the event
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function hide_modal() {
    // hide modal logic here

    // Create a custom event
    const event = new Event('modal_hide');
    // Dispatch the event
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

// Listen for the event.
window.addEventListener('modal_show', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);
window.addEventListener('modal_hide', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);
```